# Adding Dropzone.js in my website.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm sure you are all aware, there is a super cool drop and upload feature that's open source on http://www.dropzonejs.com/#layout. Now, it seems that everything is all written, the CSS and JavaScript; and all I need to do is add it to my code. However, after much trial and error, I could not make it work and I would love to have your guidance (by the way, I started web development like 9 days ago so I'm pretty much super noob).

So the first thing that I couldn't get to work is under the first part of the website which is installation (I know... I'm so noob): https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/gh-pages/examples/simple.html. And I think this is the Dropzone in it's essence, that is, without the CSS. So I copied and pasted the code, but it didn't work. There, it said,

```
<!--
  DO NOT SIMPLY COPY THOSE LINES. Download the JS and CSS files from the
  latest release (https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/releases/latest), and
  host them yourself!
-->
```

So I didn't really know what that meant because when I looked at the source, http://www.dropzonejs.com/examples/simple.html, it had exact same code as the https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/gh-pages/examples/simple.html. And it seemed to be working fine. But when I copied and pasted the source code into my index.html, it didn't work.

Anybody know why this isn't working for me when I copy and paste the source code into my own index.html?

Comment: @Destination Designs is correct. If it still doesn't work , then reproduce the issue in fiddle , so that we can fix it

Comment: @J Santosh, hey is it okay if I ask some questions regarding the dropzone.js in chat?

Comment: Awesome. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89343/room-for-harshad-and-ishwar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means download and save the scripts to your own server and include them on your page like you would any other script file, so that you are not using their resources to host script files on your sites.

[Download](https://raw.github.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.js) the standalone dropzone.js and include it like this:

include in your index.html head as

```
<script src="your/local/path/to/dropzone.js"></script>
```

Download the standalone dropzone.css and include is like this:

include in your index.html head as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your/local/path/to/dropzone.css">
```

Comment: One question... How do i find out my local path to dropzone?

Comment: I'm on a mac and I know which files I stored it in, but do I start with Home?

Comment: what ever your project folder is in and then use relative paths (google it)